# Storing specific datetime format in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, solr

This is the datetime format SOLR requires:

```
1995-12-31T23:59:59Z
```

When I try to store this as a datetime field in MySQL it says it isn't valid. My question is, ideally I would want to keep a datetime in my database so I can sort by date rather than just making it a varchar. How is it best to do this in my circumstance?

Comment: my dear fellow, use solr as a storage then to power the search and sort! rather to use mysql

Comment: Thank you for the reply but for the admin panel and various other reasons I still want to be able to sort mysql db by date itself. I dont really want to save my date as a varchar

Comment: in varchar, the results is still sortable :)

Comment: @ajreal and this is a valid varchar `1995-13-32T83:49:59Z`

Comment: [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) should help. What you see is just a representation of the internal datetime store - you can choose how to represent it.

Comment: Keep in mind that SOLR stores all dates in UTC format (designated by the trailing "Z"). So you might need to adjust accordingly when storing in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would need to look like '1995-12-31 23:59:59' to be stored in the database as a DATETIME field without throwing an error.

If you needed to pull it out of the database in the form you're presenting you can always do something like:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(timestamp_field,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as solrDate from table;
```

Comment: That looks like a nice solution. Can this be made as a function instead do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DATETIME data type.  The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

See this article: [DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @Jimmy....gotcha.  You could store in DATETIME and then do a little string manipulation before passing to SOLR for searching.  If I understand the requirement correctly

Comment: @Jimmy....how about adding another VARCHAR column for 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z and using a DATETIME column for 1995-12-31 23:59:59 to sort on?

Comment: I can do, it means saving a nearly identical thing twice though which seems a shame. Is there a function to transform it perhaps?